# Incremental categories from JSON

Tags: c#, json

I want to incrementally retrieve the root categories, subcategories, and subcategories of subcategories from JSON files.

**How can I get all categories, subcategories, and subcategories of subcategories "automatically". At this time I only get the root categories and subcategories of root.**

Every category and sub-category may have any number of categories.

Here is my CategoriesData.cs file:

```
public class CategoriesData
{
   public List<Categories> categories { get; set; }
}
```

Categories.cs file:

```
public class Categories
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public SubCategories subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

SubCategories.cs file

```
public class SubCategories
{
    public List<ChildCat> children_categories { get; set; }
}
```

ChildCat.cs

```
public class ChildCat
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example of a JSON file:

Root categories: (root.json)

```
{
  "id": "root",
  "name": "categories",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "cat1",
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "id": "cat2",
      "name": "name2"
    },
    {
      "id": "cat3",
      "name": "name3"
    },
    {
      "id": "cat4",
      "name": "name4"
    },
    {
      "id": "cat5",
      "name": "name5"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I navigate into any of the categories JSON looks like: (In this example I navigated into "cat1") (cat1.json)

```
{
  "id": "cat1",
  "name": "name1",
  "path_from_root": [
    {
      "id": "cat1",
      "name": "name1"
    }
  ],
  "children_categories": [
    {
      "id": "cat6",
      "name": "name6"
    },
    {
      "id": "cat7",
      "name": "name7"
    }
 ]
}
```

If I navigate into the children category, cat6, the JSON looks like: (file: cat6.json)

```
{
  "id": "cat6",
  "name": "name6",
  "path_from_root": [
    {
      "id": "cat1",
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "id": "cat6",
      "name": "name6"
    }
  ],
  "children_categories": [
    {
      "id": "cat8",
      "name": "name8"
    },
    {
      "id": "cat9",
      "name": "name9"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I navigate into the cat9 and there are no more children categories the file looks like: (childen_categories array is empty) (file: cat9.json)

```
{
  "id": "cat9",
  "name": "name9",
  "path_from_root": [
    {
      "id": "cat1",
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "id": "cat6",
      "name": "name6"
    },
    {
      "id": "cat9",
      "name": "name9"
    }
  ],
  "children_categories": [
  ],
}
```

I implement this to get root categories and sub categories:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

CategoriesData categoriesData;

categoriesData = serializer.Deserialize<CategoriesData>(root.json);

foreach (var item in categoriesData.categories)
{
                    string json = string.Format("{0}.json", item.id);
                    item.subcategories = serializer.Deserialize<SubCategories>(json);

}
```

Comment: Merge all files into a single file then try your code

Comment: Do you really think that it was an answer?

Comment: First of all it's a comment not an answer but I really do. What did *you* think while creating these files?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to write a recursive function for that, something like:

```
private static readonly JavaScriptSerializer Serializer =
    new JavaScriptSerializer();

private static Category FillCategory(Category category)
{
    var path = string.Format("{0}.json", category.Id);
    var text = File.ReadAllText(path);
    var result = Serializer.Deserialize<Category>(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Children_Categories.Count; i++)
        result.Children_Categories[i] =
            FillCategory(result.Children_Categories[i]);

    return result;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("root.json");
var categoriesData = Serializer.Deserialize<CategoriesData>(text);

var categories = categoriesData.Categories.Select(FillCategory).ToList();
```

This assumes you modified your model to actually match the JSON, i.e. no `SubCategories` class.